# How to ignore GPS location changes when using moveCamera with MyLocation enabled

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to move the camera to a position (defined by the user by using a search location activity), however, as my map has MyLocation enabled, when I call moveCamera/animateCamera, the GPS detects current location and ignores my moveCamera command.

How can I ignore this locations changes when using MyLocation while still having the current location button enabled (which disappears if I disable MyLocation)?

Comment: Just disable the location listener

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

> googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
>   googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(GEO, 5));
>               googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13), 3000, null);

Comment: This is the current code (not exactly in the same order) which causes the problem.